# select quantity of all products

Tags: sql, select

how to select quantity of all products in all shop, including child shop.

```
Product_ID  Brand   Shop_ID
1           Bosco   10
2           Kenzo   11
3           SARA    11
4           iStyle  13
5           Patric  13
6           Kenzo   13
7           SARA    13
8           iStyle  14
9           Patric  15

Shop_ID Shop    Parent_Shop_ID
10      Shop1   
11      Shop2   10
12      Shop3   10
13      Shop4   11
14      Shop5   11
15      Shop6   14
```

The result have to be:

```
Shop_ID    Shop     Quantity_Brands
10         Shop1    9
11         Shop2    8
12         Shop3    0
13         Shop4    4
14         Shop5    2
15         Shop6    1
```

What is the correct select ?

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. Can you please share the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry, just have updated issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given data and the *products in all shops* requests the only possible solution to your question is

```
select count(*) from products
```

But i guess your problem is more difficult?!

Answer (score 0):

I have change the database structure and other things two check it this suits you this method you can get info quickly.

Assuming QTC = Quantity available from certain products
I have another suggestion you can also store quantity available in separate table so you don't have to update details in master table because updating master table frequently is not a good practice
Table Product

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| p_id   | int(50)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| shp_id | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| qtc    | int(25)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table shops

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| shp_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



SELECT shop.name, SUM(product.qtc) FROM shop INNER JOIN product ON shop.shp_id = product.shp_id GROUP BY shop.shp_id
```